# Material-UI : how to overwrite makeStyles classes for custom component with spread operator in props

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a custom component which extends Material-UI's `Typography` component.

The component is for a template I'm creating, so I want to include the option to overwrite the default classes. A very basic guide is [provided by Material-UI here](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#makestyles) however it doesn't provide details about how to do this when you can't simply pass all props to `useStyles(props)`.

I can't pass all `props` to `useStyles(props)` as:

1. Some of the props take in default values that need to be defined
2. Since it's extending the `Typography` component, some of the props are destructured (for use in the new custom component) while all remaining props are passed to the `Typography` component using a spread operator.
3. Some of the props are only used for styling purposes (i.e. only used to be passed in as props to `useStyles(props)`. If I pass in **all** props to `useStyles(props)` then this causes an issue with point 2 above, as I'm unable to destructure these styling-only props so they get passed into the `Typography` component as part of the spread operator.

Here's some code to illustrate the issue:

```
// useStyles()

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  /** Styles applied to the root element */
  root: (props: StylesProps) => ({
    color: theme.palette.primary.main,
    fontFamily: props.fontFamily,
    fontWeight: props.weight,
    letterSpacing: props.letterSpacing,
    lineHeight: 1,
    textTransform: props.casing
  }),
  /** Styles applied to the second logo text if `name[1] !== undefined` */
  nameEnd: {
    color: theme.palette.secondary.main
  },
  /** Styles applied to the root element if `textShadow=true` */
  textShadow: {
    textShadow: theme.textShadow
  }
}));
```

```
// Component

const Logo = React.forwardRef(function Logo(props: LogoProps, ref) {
  const {
    casing = "uppercase", // HAS ISSUES 1, 2 and 3
    className,
    fontFamily, // HAS ISSUES 2 and 3
    letterSpacing, // HAS ISSUES 2 and 3
    name,
    nameSpacing = false,
    textShadow = true, // HAS ISSUES 1, 2 an 3
    weight, // HAS ISSUES 2 and 3
    ...other
  } = props;

  const stylesProps: StylesProps = {
    casing,
    fontFamily,
    letterSpacing,
    weight
  };

  const tiqClasses = useStyles(stylesProps);

  const [nameStart, nameEnd] = name;

  function LogoText(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {nameStart}
        {nameSpacing && " "}
        {nameEnd && <span className={tiqClasses.nameEnd}>{nameEnd}</span>}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Typography
      className={clsx(className, tiqClasses.root, {
        [tiqClasses.nameEnd]: nameEnd,
        [tiqClasses.textShadow]: textShadow
      })}
      component="p"
      ref={ref}
      {...other}
    >
      <LogoText />
    </Typography>
  );
});
```

If I change the code to:

```
// Component

const Logo = React.forwardRef(function Logo(props: LogoProps, ref) {
  const {
    className,
    name,
    nameSpacing = false,
    ...other
  } = props;

  const tiqClasses = useStyles(props);

  const [nameStart, nameEnd] = name;

  function LogoText(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {nameStart}
        {nameSpacing && " "}
        {nameEnd && <span className={tiqClasses.nameEnd}>{nameEnd}</span>}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Typography
      className={clsx(className, tiqClasses.root, {
        [tiqClasses.nameEnd]: nameEnd,
        [tiqClasses.textShadow]: textShadow
      })}
      component="p"
      ref={ref}
      {...other}
    >
      <LogoText />
    </Typography>
  );
});
```

Then it means that:

- `casing` and `textShadow` props no longer have default values
- `casing`, `fontFamily`, `letterSpacing` and `weight` are all passed to the `Typography` component under the `...other` spread operator since they're no longer being destructured. These are not valid props for the `Typography` component so they get passed down as a DOM attribute, which then causes errors as they are not valid DOM attributes either.

**What I want to achieve**

I want to be able to overwrite the `root`, `nameEnd` and `textShadow` classes by using the component like so:

```
<Logo tiqClasses={{ root: "rootOverwriteClass", nameEnd: "nameEndOverwriteClass" }} classes={{ body1: "body1OverwriteClass" }} {...otherProps} />
```

*I would **much** prefer to do this with `makeStyles` than `withStyles`.*

**Note:** Just to clarify, I'm using `tiqClasses` instead of `classes` as `classes` is already being used by Material-UI. You can see this in the example above where I use different names for each.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I have an idea, but can you provide a codepen so that I can verify, that it works for you ?

Comment: I actually figured out a workaround. Instead of extending TypographyProps, I just created a new prop called `typographyProps` and put all the Typography component props under there.